# How can I create a function to display an array as a tree?

Tags: php

How can I create a function to display an array as a tree. For example I want to obtain a decision tree which I want to walk until I get to the leafs based on the branch's values.  I create the tree like bellow:

```
 $tree= new DS_Tree();
 $node=array('name' => 'start');

 $tree->insert_node($node);
 $tree->goto_root();

  $mytree = new id3();
  $mytree->init($data_array_AttrList,$data_array_values,$data_class,$data_array_instances,$tree); 
  $mytree->run();
  echo '<pre class="brush: php">';
        print_r($mytree->tree->draw_tree());
  echo '</pre>';
```

The function `draw_tree()` is:

```
public function draw_tree() {
    return $this->nodes;
}
```

The function that creates my tree is:

```
private function make_tree($attr) {
    foreach($this->Values[$attr] as $v) {
        $subset = $this->get_subset($attr, $v);
        if($the_class = $this->has_same_class($subset)) {
            $node =array(
                'name' => $attr,
                 'arc' => $v

           );
            $this->tree->insert_node($node);

            $this->Instance = array_diff_key($this->Instance, $subset); 
        } else {
            $node =array(
                'name' => $this->Classa,
                'arc' => $v
            );

            $unresolved = $this->tree->insert_node($node);
       }
    }

    if (isset($unresolved)) {

        $this->tree->goto_index($unresolved);

    }

    }
}
```

The result is:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [name] => Time
        [parent] => 
        [children] => Array
            (
                [0] => 1
            )

    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [name] => Focus
        [arc] => Array
            (
                [0] => 2 day/week
                [1] => 3 day/week
                [2] => 4 day/week
                [3] => 5 day/week
                [4] => 6 day/week
            )

        [parent] => 0
        [children] => Array
            (
                [0] => 2
            )

    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [name] => Dificulty
        [arc] => Array
            (
                [0] => Weght loss
                [1] => Mantain weight
                [2] => Gain Mass
            )

        [parent] => 1
        [children] => Array
            (
                [0] => 3
            )

    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [name] => Sex
        [arc] => Array
            (
                [0] => Beginner
                [1] => Intermediar
                [2] => Advance
            )

        [parent] => 2
        [children] => Array
            (
                [0] => 4
            )

    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [name] => Array
            (
                [Exercise] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => Ex1  
                                [1] => Ex2
                                [2] => Ex3
                                [3] => Ex4
                                [4] => Ex5

                            )

                    )

            )

        [arc] => Array
            (
                [0] => F
                [1] => M
            )

        [parent] => 3
    )

)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to display an array as a tree:

```
echo "<pre>";
var_dump($array);
echo "</pre>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to iterate through this data structure and look for a certain value:

```
function recurseFind($tree, $find, $path = "") {
    if (!is_array($tree)) {
        // it is a leaf:
        if ($tree === $find) {
             return $path; // return path where we found it
        }
        return false;
    }
    foreach($tree as $key => $value) {
        $result = recurseFind($value, $find, $path . (is_numeric($key) ? "[$key]" : "['$key']"));
        if ($result !== false) return $result;
    }
    return false;
}
```

For the sample input you provided, if you would call it like this:

```
echo recurseFind($tree, "Mantain weight", '$tree');
```

Outputs the "location" of that value (first match only) in a format that can be evaluated in PHP:

```
$tree[2]['arc'][1]
```

Comment: and how can I walk this tree ? because I want to compare it with the input data from user

Comment: Can you update your question and give an example of such input, and which output you desire from that?

Comment: If the user introduce an input like this for example: Time=2 days/week, Focus= maintain weight and Difficulty=advance....then the output to be= Ex2 (for example)

Comment: Hmmm, I don't really understand this in light of the example data: I think you have a shift in your example data, because the "Focus" part actually has the "2 days/week" value, ...etc. Also, I don't see how you would determine the output to be "Ex2" (why not "Ex3"?). Anyway I updated my answer to work only with the value part. It returns the path to that value. I think you'll now be able to adapt that to your needs.

Comment: Thank you,I understand what you did. My data base contain some information for example:                                                                               F,2 day/week/,maintain weight, advance,Ex2      .           F,5/day/week/maintain weight, intermediar, Ex3                                                     B,3 day/week,gain mass,intermediar,Ex1...etc   . Based on it i create my tree and I want to use it to  make a recomandation(an Ex) to a user.

Comment: So does it answer your question? Or did I misunderstand?

Comment: This was not an complete answer but base on it i looked my code again and i realized how walk my array tree.

Comment: It was not clear to me what you were after from your question, but I am glad I could contribute to your solution. Hope you can appreciate it.